# Python selenium get redirected url with Phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my problem: I'm trying to use selenium to access a webpage and the special about this page is it is an auto redirecting page (you open that page and after few seconds, it automatically redirect to another page). When i use `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`, my IDM catched that link just perfectly after few seconds.

[image]

And because i don't want the browser to come up so i use Phantomjs instead, ut it not working. My application just can get the loading page url (bitdl-1336...) but not the redirected link. Please help!

This is my code:

```
link = 'http://torrent.ajee.sh/hash.php?hash=' + self.global_hash_code
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('phantomjs.exe')
driver.get(str(link))
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download Zip')
element.click()
time.sleep(10)
msg = QMessageBox.information(self, QString('Thành công'),QString(driver.current_url))
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Please help!

Sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your PhantomJS-specific question, but a workaround to the problem.

> And because i don't want the browser to come up so i use Phantomjs instead

You can continue using Firefox, but start it in a *Virtual Display*, see more information at:

- [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)

You may also need to let the browser automatically save the archive in a specified directory, see:

- [How do I automatically download files from a pop up dialog using selenium-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852709/how-do-i-automatically-download-files-from-a-pop-up-dialog-using-selenium-python)
- [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

Comment: i'll try! and actually i don't want my browser to save file, just get it's link! :)

Comment: It not work bro! search alot online and maybe Xvfb does't work on windows! :(