# Sending "Enter" key to browser window

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for an opportunity to send "Enter" key to browser window, not to web element(to confirm the appearing save dialog). Is it possible?

Comment: Is the save dialog appearing as an alert?

Comment: Could you share this dialog HTML if it's not a JavaScript dialog??

Comment: The save dialog is standart firefox' save dialog

Comment: Seems to be similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852709/how-do-i-automatically-download-files-from-a-pop-up-dialog-using-selenium-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in python, but other language will be similar. You should be able to use `driver.switch_to.alert` when the alert appears, which returns the `alert` object. If you just want to confirm the alert, use `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`. Sending the `enter` key would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Get to stage where alert appears
# Send enter key
driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

You may need to use E[xpected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) to wait for the alert to actually appear.