# How to download XML file using Firefox driver, Selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am writing a script using Selenium to export an XML backup from the export page of a MediaWiki-based website.

I wish to download the XML file to a directory, bypassing the popup window that usually asks me what to do with the file.

When I look at the Network tab when downloading the .xml, file I see (under Response Headers) that content-type is **application/xml; charset=utf-8**.

[Screenshot from Network tab on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM5n3.png)

After reading some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852709/how-do-i-automatically-download-files-from-a-pop-up-dialog-using-selenium-python?lq=1), as well as [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/42hg1c/selenium_download_wont_automatically_save_without/), I am using:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain, application/octet-stream, text/xml, application/xml")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, executable_path=r'C:\Python37\geckodriver.exe')
(...)
download_button.click()
```

However, the window still pops up and the file is not downloaded anywhere.

I made sure to update Selenium and the geckodriver.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much trial-and-error for me this worked (it's Java but should be transferable to Python):

```java
profile.setPreference("browser.download.viewableInternally.previousHandler.alwaysAskBeforeHandling.xml", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.viewableInternally.previousHandler.preferredAction.xml", 0);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.viewableInternally.typeWasRegistered.xml", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass a tuple as an argument, like this:

```
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', (text/plain, application/octet-stream, text/xml, application/xml))
```

It works for me.
PS: Ignore my poor english, I'm brazilian.