# Selenium deal with download diaglogs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to download some files (.3ds).
I am using FireFox (v94.0.1 64-bit), but am fine to use another browser if it will help.
I am using MacOS.

The issue is that when I click a download link, a dialog is shown:
[image]

I don't want any user input; this should all be automatic.
I need to get Selenium to click `save file`, check `do this automatically...`, and then click `OK`.

I have tried the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852709/how-do-i-automatically-download-files-from-a-pop-up-dialog-using-selenium-python) post, but the dialog is always shown:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Users/myusername/Downloads")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser.maximize_window()
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code, just needs to be set_preference for 3ds file.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/3ds, application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False);
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/Users/myusername/Downloads")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
browser.maximize_window()
```